# Javascript equivalent of Perl hash table comparisons

Tags: javascript

I am relatively new to Javascript and have a need to do something that is easy for me to code up in Perl, but I cannot quite figure out the Javascript equivalent. Two arrays were populated with the contents of text windows named baseText and newText, where each window has very simple lines like A = 1, B = 5, etc.:-

```
function myJSComparator() {
    var baseEntries = stringAsLines(byId("baseText").value);
    var baseAllAppOptions = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < baseEntries.length; i++) {
        var fields = baseEntries[i].split("=");
        var baseAppOption = {optionName:fields[0],optionValue:fields[1]};
        baseAllAppOptions.push(baseAppOption);
    }
    var newEntries = stringAsLines(byId("newText").value);
    var newAllAppOptions = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < newEntries.length; i++) {
        var fields = newEntries[i].split("=");
        var newAppOption = {optionName:fields[0],optionValue:fields[1]};
        newAllAppOptions.push(newAppOption);
    }
}
```

How do I iterate over baseAllAppOptions and newAllAppOptions and output the following:-

1) A summary of only the optionName.fields that are the same in both baseAllAppOptions and newAllAppOptions, but whose corresponding optionValue.fields are different.

2) A summary of only the optionName.fields (and their corresponding optionValue.fields) that are in baseAllAppOptions, but not in newAllAppOptions.

3) A summary of only the optionName.fields (and their corresponding optionValue.fields) that are in the newAllAppOptions, but not in baseAllAppOptions.

I have three text windows waiting to receive the outputs of each line above. I plan to print to each text window like so...

```
    for (var i = 0; i < baseEntries.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("baseChangeText").value += baseAllAppOptions[i].optionName + baseAllAppOptions[i].optionValue + String.fromCharCode(13);
    }
```

The above is just an example of how I would iterate over the array entries and print them out without doing any direct comparisons. But I need the format to be what is described in the document.getElementById line.

Any general guidance that can be shared would be much appreciated!

BTW, here is what I am working with:-

https://jsfiddle.net/e4bunLvh/57/

In each "Release #* App Option Defaults" window, just add something like A = 1 to both and then B = 2 in one and C = 3 in another.

Thanks!

Comment: Please click `<>` snippet editor and add relevant input and expected output in a [mcve]

Comment: Sample data would be great.

Comment: i'm thinking the lodash functions `differenceBy`, `intersectionBy` and `xorBy` will be useful here but i'm having trouble conceptualizing it without sample input and output data. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#xorBy

Comment: I just added a simple JSFiddle link. Does that help?

Comment: Maybe add the P5 code you would use so we can see what exact transformation you're trying to perform?

Comment: If the Release #1 text box has A = 1 followed by B = 2, and Release #2 text box has A = 1 followed by C = 3, I would expect the following outputs:-  

App option values that changed between Release #1 and Release #2: empty  
App options unique to Release #1: B = 2  
App options unique to Release #2: C = 3  <br/>

That's it! The actual inputs will be several thousand lines long, but the above is a simplified input.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert each set of options to an object (equivalent to a hash in Perl), then it should be a simple matter of looping through the keys (and using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) makes this simple) and simply testing for a difference in value, or defined-ness.

Example:

```js
var getObjectWithContents = function(elementId) {
  return document.getElementById(elementId)
    .value
    .trim()
    .replace('\r\n', '\n') // replace Windows linebreaks to Unix
    .replace('\n\n', '\n') // replace double-linebreaks to single
    .split('\n').map(function(line) { // map into single key-value pairs
      var value = line.split('=');
      var key = value[0].trim();
      var val = value[1].trim();
      var o = {};
      o[key] = val;
      return o;
    }).reduce(function(o, p) { // reduce array of single key-value pairs to one object
      var key = Object.keys(p).shift();
      var val = p[key];
      o[key] = val;
      return o;
    }, {});
};

var getDifferenceByValue = function(optionsBase, optionsNew) {
  var difference = [];

  Object.keys(optionsBase).forEach(function(key) {
    var baseValue = optionsBase[key]; // 
    var newValue = optionsNew[key];

    if (newValue !== undefined && baseValue !== newValue) {
      difference.push(key);
    }
  });

  return difference;
};

var getDifferenceByOption = function(a, b) {
  var difference = {};

  Object.keys(a).forEach(function(key) {
    if (b[key] === undefined) {
      difference[key] = a[key];
    }
  });

  return difference;
};

var outputToTextarea = function outputToTextarea(area, o, type) {
  var text = document.getElementById(area);
  text.value = Object.keys(o).map(function(key) {
    return key + '=' + o[key];
  }).join('\n');
};

var outputDiffByValue = function outputDiffByValue(array) {
  var text = document.getElementById('outputByValue');
  text.value = array.join('\n');
};

var getDiff = function getDiff() {
  var app1Defaults = getObjectWithContents('baseText');
  var app2Defaults = getObjectWithContents('newText');

  var stuffInBothWithDifferentValues = getDifferenceByValue(app1Defaults, app2Defaults);
  var stuffInBaseAndNotInNew = getDifferenceByOption(app1Defaults, app2Defaults);
  var stuffInNewAndNotInBase = getDifferenceByOption(app2Defaults, app1Defaults);

  outputDiffByValue(stuffInBothWithDifferentValues);
  outputToTextarea('diffBase', stuffInBaseAndNotInNew);
  outputToTextarea('diffNew', stuffInNewAndNotInBase);

  // console.log({
  //     stuffInBothWithDifferentValues,
  //     stuffInBaseAndNotInNew,
  //     stuffInNewAndNotInBase,
  // });
};

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var button = document.getElementById('logDiff');
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    getDiff();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }, false);
}, false);
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea class="textbox" id="baseText" rows="5">
  a = 1
  b = 2
  c = 2
  f = 5
  </textarea>
  <textarea class="textbox" id="newText" rows="5">
  a = 0
  b = 1
  d = 3
  e = 4
  </textarea>
  <button id="logDiff">Get Differences</button>
</div>
<div>
  <h3><label for="outputByValue">Differences by Value</label></h3>
  <textarea class="textbox" id="outputByValue" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <h3><label for="diffBase">Stuff in Base (but not in New)</label></h3>
  <textarea class="textbox" id="diffBase" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <h3><label for="diffNew">Stuff in New (but not in Base)</label></h3>
  <textarea class="textbox" id="diffNew" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>
```